# Finding the middle index value of an array in a binary search algorithm in Python

Tags: python-3.x, binary-search

I am new to Python and implementing a binary search algorithm. Here is the algorithm:

```
def binary_search(list, item):
    low = 0     
    high = len(list)-1

    while low <= high:
        mid = (low + high)
        guess = list[mid]

        if guess == item:
            return mid      
        if guess > item:
            high = mid - 1      
        else:
            low = mid + 1   
    return None
```

My question is in regard to the line `mid = (low + high)`. The algorithm returns the correct index location for any item in the array whether I use `mid = (low + high)` or `mid = (low + high)/2`. Why is that? I have searched everywhere for an explanation for this specific question and cannot find one. All I've found is that Python 3 automatically rounds down numbers that are not evenly divisible, so for an array with an odd number of elements, like 13, the index of the middle element will be 6. But how does the algorithm above get to the middle index element without dividing by 2 every time?

Comment: Print out high, low, and mid at each step, and see what is happening.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because your algorithm isn't a binary search.

```
mid = (low + high)
```

Since high starts at `len(arr) - 1` and low always starts at `0` mid always starts at `len(arr) - 1`.

```
if guess > item:
    high = mid - 1
```

In this case in the next recalculation of `mid` the value of `mid` decreases by one. So if the guess is too high it goes down one element. The thing is since `mid` always starts at `len(arr) - 1`, this will always be `True`. `guess` will always start out as the largest element and then go down one by one. Until you hit:

```
if guess == item:
    return mid
```

In which case you just return the item. Your algorithm searches for the item linearly from the last element to the first in a one by one manner.

If you actually add a `print(low, high, mid)` you'll get an output like this:

```
0 6 6
0 5 5
0 4 4
0 3 3
0 2 2
0 1 1
0 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that answer! What should I change to make it a binary search?

Comment: `mid = (high + low) / 2`. You may have to work out a few bugs though, like `high = mid - 1  ` should probably be `high = mid`. But there are plenty of binary search implementations online: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/binary-search/